# Access nested Immutable Map property

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I'm learning Immutable.js. I have an object that when called:

`myObj.get('people')`

returns the following:

```
[
  {
    "name": "John Stevenson",
    "country": "Sweden"
  },
  {
    "name": "John Silva",
    "country": "Colombia"
  },
  {
    "name": "John Van der Bier",
    "country": "Holland"
  },
  {
    "name": "John McDonald",
    "country": "Scotland"
  }
]
```

I'm trying to get inside this object so I can only see `country`:

`myObj.getIn(['people', 'country']) // undefined`

What am I missing?

Comment: The accessor that you describe would be if the object was formed like this 
`{ people: { country: 'somecountry' } }`

But in your case the value of people is an array not another object with a key and value. What is your end goal? do you want an array of only the countries for each person?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with you're code is that the result of `getIn(['people', 'country'])` is attempting to access the `country` property of `people`, which is an array and doesn't have a property named country. It seems like want to loop over people and build an array of their countries, which you can do with `map`:

```
var countries = myObj.get('people').map(person => {
    return person.country
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer will return an array. If you are truly wanting to use Immutable you should use

```
import { fromJS } from 'Immutable';
const immutableObj = fromJS(myObj);

//map() or forEach() here
var countries = immutableObj.map(person => {
    return person.get('country');
})
```